# Shell script when executed appears twice is the process list

Tags: unix

I am running the below shell script to run in background ./something.sh &

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -n0 -f -F service.log | while read LOGLINE
do
done
```

when i check ps -ef| grep something, i see two processes

```
20273     1  0 16:13 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /something.sh 
20280 20273  0 16:13 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /something.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your script is piping the output of a program to a shell command. When you run this there will be three processes:

1. The `something.sh` that you explicitly started
2. The `tail` that your script starts
3. A copy of `something.sh` that is executing the `while` loop.

Comment: Yes there are 3 processes, what do you mean by 3rd point, as there is a infinite while loop do you say there will be one more process gets created ?

Comment: I mean `bash` has forked itself into two copies, one to be the controlling shell and one to be the receiving shell which runs the `while` loop. No `while` running, and you won't have that second copy. Since `while` is a shell built in (I called it "shell command" above"), it shows up as `bash` again in the process list.